# How to show "custom field" a user profile in a Taxonomy view?

Tags: views

I have a view set to show the content where I show the taxonomy and fields of a Content Type. At this point I added a Phone field in the user profile in> "config/people/accounts/fields". How do I filter and display the user's Phone field in the table where the Taxonomy terms are displayed? The view is set to show the content and, of course, you don't allow me to choose the Phone field I added in the user profile. I need to show this field to view the phone numbers of specific users who created the node.

Any suggestion?

Best Regards

Comment: Have you added a relationship to the User who created the content?

Comment: Great! Solved :) Best Regards